# php set timer then call a function

Tags: php, timer, youtube

i have a youtube video which I get its duration in seconds, I want to set a timer for that video and once it's done then call a function which has a different video.  So far what i have is this:

```
$ytvidid = 'qasCLgrauAg';
$ytdataurl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $ytvidid;
$feedURL = $ytdataurl;
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$media = $sxml->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
// get <yt:duration> node for video length
$yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
$attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
$length = $attrs['seconds'];
```

that returns in this example 16 seconds, so i've tried:

```
usleep($length * 1000000);
flush();
loadnext();

function loadnext(){
    //heres my next video
}
```

for some reason this doesn't work..am i doing something wrong? I've also tried javascript window.setInterval(...) but that doesn't work either in reseting the interval when the next video loads.  Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after several hours of reading I figured out what I wanted to accomplish could not be done with php's sleep or usleep functions.. So I finally got it working with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = 1;
next(id);
var t;
function setValue(time, rowid)
{

    id = rowid;
    t = setInterval(cleartime, time * 1000);    
}

function cleartime()
{
    clearInterval(t);
    next(parseInt(id, 10));
}
function next(id){
    //this gets values and calls the setValue function again        
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

for `16 seconds` delay you have to use

```
usleep($length * 1000000);  // 1000000 == 1 second
```

Comment: thanks changed it, yet instead of waiting the 16 seconds to call that function it calls it immediatly..

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing in seconds (not microseconds), you might consider using [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) instead of [`usleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php).